# Errors in superuser and stack overflow

Tags: bug, chat

Whenever I click on 'chat' I get some message about my number of posts being been limited and will expire in 3 days, but this is for the 'forum' (whatever its called) not for the chat room, and its been longer than it stated.

And when I go to Stack overflow and click 'chat' I get an error of a cat saying theres a problem, I have asked in another chat room called Charcoal HQ

Here is the message in question for superuser, it happens when I click any room in superuser chat index

[image]

Here is another error I've had for over a week now for stackoverflow: (chat.stackoverflow.com)

[image]

Comment: You don't have enough reputation to enter a chat room on Superuser or any Stackexchange website at this time.  Be sure you are allowing all scripts on the website.

Comment: http://superuser.com/help/privileges Chat requires 20 rep. You are very close.

Comment: while I do only have 17 reputation it does not contemplate the errors I'm getting and I doubt having 20 reputation will fix them

Comment: That's odd. I wonder if a question ban, and that contributed somehow. You also have one question that was flagged offensive. Can you give a screenshot of the actual error?

Comment: the only errors I get are above

Comment: @DavidPostill - When I submitted that comment the user had 17 reputation at Superuser.  Since he submitted this question somebody upvoted one of their answers.

Answer (score 4):

You appear to have an unfortunate habit of [lashing out](https://superuser.com/questions/985352/what-the-fuck-serioustly) (10k only link) and posting questions that are "shouting" or contain vulgar language.

As a result the community probably flagged some of your questions as "rude or abusive". Questions or answers flagged in this way are treated very similarly to spam and will end up rate limiting and potentially blocking a user in the ways you have seen.

The best course of action is to remain calm while asking questions. Don't swear, keep to the point, and ask clear and concise questions.

We require that all users [be nice](https://superuser.com/help/be-nice):

> **Rudeness and belittling language are not okay.** Your tone should match the way you'd talk in person with someone you respect and whom you want to respect you.

Rude language, irrespective of who or what it is targeted at, is not tolerated here and is considered abusive.